# Kotlin как настроить начальный экран

Tags: android, kotlin, layout

Настроил AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.mugan86.qrscanner.AuthActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ScannerViewActivity" />
```

И по идеи должен был запускаться .AuthActivity

Но запускается почему то .MainActivity

Comment: попробуйте удалить полностью приложение с эмулятора и снова запустите в AS проект, может старый манифест подтягивается

Comment: Все равно грузится не тот layout. Уже и apk файл на телефон кидал и в эмуляторе удалял.

Comment: Так дело, наверное, не в манифесте, а в том какой макет вы устанавливаете в функции `onCreate` активности: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_????)`